# React-admin | How to concat source inside ReferenceField

Tags: admin-on-rest, api-platform.com, react-admin

I have a table "fos_user" and "version", I would like to display "9.0.1.A" instead of "/ version / 1".

**=>fos_user**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z9LG.png

**=>version**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCu9v.png

Is it possible to concatenate the fields of the "version" table to display it in the source, like this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKsWQ.png

Because it will prevent me from creating a new field in the "version" table.

Best regards,

Comment: i managed to do it with this code,i hope it will be useful to someone: https://i.imgur.com/NMLLcM8.png

Comment: Very nice implementation. You can write the solution as answer of your question and mark it a "resolved your question"!

Comment: could you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Here is some help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**React-admin | How to concat source inside ReferenceField ?**

*Answer:*

`` <ReferenceField label="Version" source="version" reference="versions">
    <FunctionField render={version => `${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}.${version.letter}`} />
</ReferenceField> ``

Answer (score 1):

I needed a prefix for images. Unfortunatelly the provided solution didn't work for me... At first I tried

```
<ImageField source="prefix + contentUrl"/>
```

and the solution above...

Eventually I found following solution:

```
const MyImageField = ({source, record = {}, ...rest}) => {
    let clonedRecord = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(record));
    clonedRecord[source] = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH + clonedRecord[source];
    return <ImageField source={source} record={clonedRecord} {...rest}/>;
};

export const ImageList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <MyImageField source="contentUrl"></MyImageField>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

const dataProvider = baseHydraDataProvider(entrypoint, fetchHydra, apiDocumentationParser);

export default () => (
    <HydraAdmin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider} entrypoint={entrypoint}>   
        <ResourceGuesser name={"media_objects"} list={ImageList}/>
    </HydraAdmin>
);
```

Somehow i needed a clone, because the function was called multiple times (-> prefix was added x times).

I use this in combination with the [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/).

Also see:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component

Answer (score 0):

From https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#reference-fields

Tip: If you want to display data from more than one field, check out the `<FunctionField>`, which accepts a render function:

```
import { FunctionField } from 'react-admin';

<FunctionField
    label="Name"
    render={record => `${record.first_name} ${record.last_name}`}
/>;
```

So for your case, it would be:

```
import { FunctionField } from 'react-admin';

<FunctionField
    label="Name"
    render={version => `${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}.${version.letter}`}
/>;
```