# API-platform/Admin: How Render ImageField with custom src?

Tags: admin, react-admin, api-platform.com

I want to inject full path to my media in admin of API-platform with
[following this doc](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/getting-started#managing-files-and-images)

was impossible to generate full path URI I try this:

```
 field.field = props => (
                        <ImageField source="contentUrl"  {...props} >
                            <FunctionField render={ render => {
                                console.log(render)
                                return `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT}/media/${render.contentUrl}`
                            }}  />
                        </ImageField>
                    );
```

from: [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418951/react-admin-how-to-concat-source-inside-referencefield/51552320#51552320)

I obtain this result:

```
<img src="[object Object]" class="ImageField-image-274">
```

my src needs to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/media/myFile.jpg
```

from my api:

```
contentUrl = myFile.jpg
```

I need concat this with `process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT`

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FunctionField` like this:

```
<FunctionField
      label="Image"
      render={(record: any) => {
        return (
          <img
            src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT}/media/${record.contentUrl}`}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the variable before you start the webpack dev server or before you build your project?

```
export REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT=http://localhost/....
npm start
```